# How can configuration values be stored on an ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, eeprom

I have a project that uses [an MQTT service](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/), and I'm wondering how to best store the configuration settings (server, user, password, port) for the service as right now they are just hard-coded into some constants.

I saw that [EEPROM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM) can be used for this but I'm not sure it is the best way. I went to look at the code for [WifiManager](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) to see how it accomplishes this task for the SSID and password since it works so well and it removed its EEPROM dependency back in 2015: https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/commit/659df9cb277c5f93946d9d8795e39a5ae5863ab1

I can't figure out how those settings are persisted.

If EEPROM *is* the best way for storing something like this, I'd like to write my values without overwriting/corrupting existing values, is that possible? How can I set the initial values of the EEPROM to the constants that I need?

**Edit:** well after digging into the [esp8266/Arduino repository](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/) I found that the [`WiFi.SSID()`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp#L480) and [`WiFi.psk()`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp#L490) settings come from `wifi_station_get_config` and stored with `wifi_station_set_config` although I haven't found how *those* work so I think EEPROM might be the way to go here, I just need a bit of guidance and clarification on the right way to use it.

Comment: as an alternative, have you considered looking into using SPIFFS (but EEPROM is fine - the parts that were removed in WifiManager had to do with storing the SSID/password - the ESP8266 already does this "natively" (don't ask, I don't know the details of where)

Comment: https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/tree/master/examples/AutoConnectWithFSParameters

Comment: @JaromandaX I haven't used SPIFFS before, I'll look into that.

Comment: +infinity for SPIFFS over EEPROM. use SPIFFS, it's easy and great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [Jaromanda X](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/21371/jaromanda-x) and [Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj) for the [SPIFFS](https://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.3.0/doc/filesystem.html#file-system-object-spiffs) recommendation. I was able to use [this block of SPIFFS code](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/blob/039702327e6c3aef2a7ccc766bcf8bbab20bdae2/examples/AutoConnectWithFSParameters/AutoConnectWithFSParameters.ino#L38-L68) as an example and safely store settings in my project outside of the compiled source.

To upload files to my ESP8266, I followed the [installation](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin#installation) and [usage](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin#usage) instructions for the [ESP8266 filesystem plugin](https://github.com/esp8266/arduino-esp8266fs-plugin) for the [standard Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software#download).

First, I created a `.gitignore` file and added this so that none of the actual values would get added to the repository:

```bash
# MQTT config info
data/config.json
```

Then I created a `data` folder and added a `config.json` file that had all the configuration properties that I need to reference:

```js
{
  "cloudmqtt_server": "***.cloudmqtt.com",
  "cloudmqtt_user": "********",
  "cloudmqtt_pass": "************",
  "cloudmqtt_port": 10000 
}
```

Following the [example above](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager/blob/039702327e6c3aef2a7ccc766bcf8bbab20bdae2/examples/AutoConnectWithFSParameters/AutoConnectWithFSParameters.ino#L38-L68), I added `#include <FS.h>` at line #1 (as well as `#include <ArduinoJson.h>` for parsing the JSON) and have this block to instantiate the variables with dummy values that will be replaced by the actual values from the JSON file:

```cpp
// MQTT pub/sub for the servo functions
#define CLOUDMQTT_CONFIG  "/config.json"
// these values are loaded from a config.json file in the data directory
char cloudmqtt_server[18] = "***.cloudmqtt.com";
int  cloudmqtt_port       = 0;
char cloudmqtt_user[9]    = "********";
char cloudmqtt_pass[13]   = "************";
```

Then in the setup I have this block to load the values from the config:

```cpp
if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
  Serial.println("mounted file system");

  // parse json config file
  File jsonFile = GetFile(CLOUDMQTT_CONFIG);
  if (jsonFile) {
    // Allocate a buffer to store contents of the file.
    size_t size = jsonFile.size();
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> jsonBuf(new char[size]);
    jsonFile.readBytes(jsonBuf.get(), size);

    DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
    JsonObject& json = jsonBuffer.parseObject(jsonBuf.get());
    if (json.success()) {
      strcpy(cloudmqtt_server, json["cloudmqtt_server"]);
      cloudmqtt_port = json["cloudmqtt_port"];
      strcpy(cloudmqtt_user, json["cloudmqtt_user"]);
      strcpy(cloudmqtt_pass, json["cloudmqtt_pass"]);
    } else {
      Serial.println("failed to load json config");
    }
    jsonFile.close();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this way works for me: 
https://github.com/dieseltravis/esp8266-projects/tree/master/servo-demo

Comment: If you use WiFiManager you could also ask for the MQTT parameters directly from the captive portal, then save to SPIFFS.